# One Large DELETE FROM WHERE NULL Or Multiple Small DELETE FROM WHERE NULLS for Better Performance?

Tags: sql-server, performance, foreach, ssis

I have a `ForEach Loop Container` that enumerates a massive amount of `Excel Files`.  All files have `NULL` rows mixed in with the populated Rows.  These need deleted upon migration into database.

What performs better: one massive `DELETE FROM foo` or multiple small `DELETE FROM foo`s within `ForEach Loop Container`?

Comment: Have a look at this answer [`How to delete large data of table in SQL without log?`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24213299/how-to-delete-large-data-of-table-in-sql-without-log)

Comment: U need 2 delete only null rows....?

Comment: @koushikveldanda Yes...Only need to delete null rows

Answer (score 0):

Set row count to 5000 and delete until done.  This is the best that I have noticed.  I delete a lot of very old transactions daily before I used this method, I had a lot of issues.

Answer (score 0):

here I used conditional split and based on that I removed nulls and passed not null rows to destination
[image]

Is this what you have asked....