# What is the fastest way to clear a SQL table?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a table with about 300,000 rows and 30 columns. How can I quickly clear it out? If I do a `DROP FROM MyTable` query, it takes a long time to run. I'm trying the following stored procedure to basically make a copy of the table with no data, drop the original table, and rename the new table as the original:

```
USE [myDatabase]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS_ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ClearTheTable]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT * INTO tempMyTable FROM MyTable WHERE 1 = 0;
    DROP TABLE MyTable
    EXEC sp_rename tempMyTable, MyTable;
END
```

This took nearly 7 minutes to run. Is there a faster way to do it? I don't need any logging, rollback or anything of that nature.

If it matters, I'm calling the stored procedure from a C# app. I guess I could write some code to recreate the table from scratch after doing a `DROP TABLE`, but I didn't want to have to recompile the app any time a column is added or changed.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Here's my updated stored procedure:

```
USE [myDatabase]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS_ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ClearTheTable]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    ALTER DATABASE myDatabase
    SET RESTRICTED_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
    TRUNCATE TABLE MyTable
    ALTER DATABASE myDatabase
    SET MULTI_USER
END
```

Comment: How about using `TRUNCATE`?

Comment: truncate will only keep skeleton of your table by clearing all values.make sure it doesn't have any constraints

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24213299/how-to-delete-large-data-of-table-in-sql-without-log

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Best way to clear a table is with [TRUNCATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177570.aspx).

Since you are creating and droping ill assume you have no constraints.

```
TRUNCATE TABLE <target table>
```

Some advantages:

> - Less transaction log space is used.
>
> The DELETE statement removes rows one at a time and records an entry
>   in the transaction log for each deleted row. TRUNCATE TABLE removes
>   the data by deallocating the data pages used to store the table data
>   and records only the page deallocations in the transaction log.
>
> - Fewer locks are typically used.
>
> When the DELETE statement is executed using a row lock, each row in
>   the table is locked for deletion. TRUNCATE TABLE always locks the
>   table (including a schema (SCH-M) lock) and page but not each row.
>
> - Without exception, zero pages are left in the table.
>
> After a DELETE statement is executed, the table can still contain
>   empty pages. For example, empty pages in a heap cannot be deallocated
>   without at least an exclusive (LCK_M_X) table lock. If the delete
>   operation does not use a table lock, the table (heap) will contain
>   many empty pages. For indexes, the delete operation can leave empty
>   pages behind, although these pages will be deallocated quickly by a
>   background cleanup process.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It sounds like it should be easy, but running `TRUNCATE TABLE myTable;` has been running for 30+ minutes. There are no foreign keys, but there are 3 indexes, if that makes a difference.

Comment: It appears my issue was due to a linked table being opened in MS Access.   I got around this by doing `SET RESTRICTED_USER`, running the truncate, then `SET MULTI_USER` right afterwards. Worked great!

Comment: According to this page: https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/truncate.php
TRUNCATE cannot be rolled back, but DELETE can. So doesn't that make DELETE the safer option?

Comment: Safer, yes. But when it comes to speed it is the best option.