# Purge the inactive records from Database in SQL server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, database-administration

The total database size is 500GB. In this database all most 250 GB is taking indexes and Inactive data.

Now I want to remove the Inactive Data? Is there any methods or architect to remove the inactive data?

Right now, I removed the data using below commands

```
delete TOP(1000) from TableName
```

After removed all the records, I applied the shrink file to release the space but I am facing to much slowness on Database side.

Any one have idea how can I remove the slowness on database?

Comment: What is your definition of 'Inactive data'?

Comment: `delete TOP(1000) from TableName?`?? This deletes 1000 *arbitrarily chosen* records from the table.

Comment: @GeorgiRaychev: Inactive means soft delete records.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner : yes. actual query is delete top(10000) from tablename where isactive=1

Comment: But why would you have the DBMS choose rows arbitrarily? Why not delete *all* inactive records or the *oldest* 10000 inactive records instead of 10000 *randomly chosen* inactive records?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner if I take all records then its increase the log file size that's why I have used the top. space is limited

Comment: Maybe this answer here helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24213299/how-to-delete-large-data-of-table-in-sql-without-log

Comment: @nirav if you can provide us with the _schema_ of the table, people can help you out exactly.
Just a headsup if there is any **date/identity** column you can use that to remove the older rows based on that.