# Azure SQL large deletes

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database, sql-delete

I am currently working with an application using an Azure hosted SQL server instance. The application data doesn't take up a ton of physical space, however there are a lot of records. There are times where I need to delete a large amount of records, for example lets say 5 million records. As you might guess this takes a lot of time and resources. The issue is that I don't need a lot of resources for anything else. In order to not peg the DTU's at 100% for 30 minutes or longer I need to have many more resources that I need under normal use. I don't care how long the delete takes within reason. From what I have researched I cannot find a good way to limit the usage. It would be nice if I could somehow only allow 50% usage for the operation or something like that. Maybe I am missing something that could make the delete more efficient, but I don't think so. Its a pretty simple table with an index on the column I am using to do the delete. It seems like the main component that gets maxed out is Data IO. If anyone has any good ideas on how I can manage this it would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: You could have a SP that deletes a bunch of records, wait a few seconds, deletes again, etc.

Comment: Also take a look at partition and truncate partiions: https://stackify.com/how-to-partition-tables-in-azure-sql/

Comment: Breaking it up I am able to drop my Log IO. The component that seems to be maxing it out is Data IO. If I delete 10,000 records it takes ~10 seconds. During this time the Data IO is spiking. I added an image of the performance graph.

Comment: Try with a smaller chunk, like 1,000 records. Remember to add a delay after each chunk. Also the CPU is going up, have you analyzed the execution plan for the delete statement? make sure you have the correct indexes.

Comment: Looking at my execution plan I also have 2 index deletes that have relatively high costs. The correct index for the delete is in place however.

Comment: I don't know what's the criteria for the delete query, have you consdiered filtered indexes? If the query is optimized correctly, then you won't get much more with this approach. You might need to consider the second option I pointed out in my solution: use partitions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Delete by chunks in a loop. Check this: [How to delete large data of table in SQL without log?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24213299/how-to-delete-large-data-of-table-in-sql-without-log/28324562#28324562)

2) Use partitions and truncate by partitions. Check this: https://stackify.com/how-to-partition-tables-in-azure-sql/

Answer (score 6):

Delete involves locating data,getting data from disk and logging those operations..

**Locating data/Minimizing IO:**
To ensure IO is minimized, you will need to add right index .
Some times some operators involved in delete may run in parallel,to avoid this , you will need to add maxdop hint to ensure nothing in this query runs parallel..

```
delete from table where somecol=someval
option(maxdop 1)
```

**Minimizing log operation:**
Every DML operation is logged,but when  you do individual deletes, you will use more log IO(which is one of the DTU metric of AZure database)..you will have to delete in batches and ensure they are in one single transaction..

```
while 1=1
begin
    delete top(1000) from table where id=someval
    if @@rowcount =0
    break;
    end
go
```

You also can partition your tables to make deletes faster.Truncate can be now used with partitions starting with sql 2016..

```
TRUNCATE TABLE tablename
WITH (PARTITIONS (1,2,3))
GO
```

the syntax also allows you to specify range..

```
[ WITH ( PARTITIONS ( { <partition_number_expression> | <range> }   
    [ , ...n ] ) ) ]
```

Partition can help you more, only if, you want to delete all or nothing of a partition.if you are doing this types of deletes more, you may need to design your table to help truncate

**Further reading and References:**
https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-2016-enhancements-truncate-table-table-partitioning/

Answer (score 1):

Loop with a delay may work. This is 10 seconds.

```
select 1
WHILE (@@ROWCOUNT > 0)
BEGIN
  DELETE TOP (10000) LargeTable 
  WHERE readTime < dateadd(MONTH,-7,GETDATE())
  WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01'
END
```