# SQL performance on many deletes

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I have a temp table full of GUIDs ##TempCleanseTheseCustomers.

I want to delete several related tables to a customer table. Around 30 related tables. Here is some examples:

```
Delete from AddressHistory
Where CustomerId in (select CustomerId From ##TempCleanseTheseCustomers)

Delete from Address
Where CustomerId in (select CustomerId From ##TempCleanseTheseCustomers)


DECLARE @MessageMessageId uniqueidentifier
set @MessageMessageId = 
(
SELECT        TOP (1)  Message.MessageId
FROM            Customer INNER JOIN
                     CustomerMessage ON Customer.CustomerId = 
CustomerMessage.CustomerId INNER JOIN
                     Message ON CustomerMessage.MessageId = 
Message.MessageId
Where Customer.CustomerId in (select CustomerId From 
##TempCleanseTheseCustomers)
)


Delete from MessageAttachment
Where MessageId = @MessageMessageId

Delete from Message
Where MessageId = @MessageMessageId
```

How can make this run as fast as possible? (##TempCleanseTheseCustomers contains over 2 million rows)

I have tried moving the table to memory. Running it via C# code etc.

Comment: Make sure your deletes aren't being blocked by other statements and the deleting tables have index on CustomerId (clustered preferably).

Comment: not for optimization tips, but you do not have `Order by` with `Top`? just a random value?

Comment: Do it in reasonable sized bulks. I.e. not millions of rows per delete, nor just one.

Comment: Here are some ways to do that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24213299/how-to-delete-large-data-of-table-in-sql-without-log

Comment: Are your `CustomerId` columns indexed?

Comment: LONG: U found an error. Thanks

Comment: Not all related tables CustomerId  was indexed. So thanks

Comment: @Per G please listen to StephaneM https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24213299/how-to-delete-large-data-of-table-in-sql-without-log

Answer (score 0):

May be you can check that there are not duplicated records on ##TempCleanseTheseCustomers and check the existence of indexes and keys on the other several tables