# Deleting large data in azure SQL table will increased Database data storage

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-storage

I'm trying to delete large data from Azure SQL table using delete command, but when deleting data then database data storage will be increased. How could I stop that or is there any option in Azure to minimize transaction logs?

I don't want to use truncate because I don't need to delete all data in the table.

```
 delete top(10000)
 from Crumbs
 where CrumbId <= @maxId and 
       TenantId =@tenantId
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would change the recovery mode of the database to SIMPLE.

It's a little bit different for Azure Sql Databases:
In this case the SQL Database Engine performs a transaction log backup every 5-10 minutes - It's also shrinked automatically.

If you want full control over your database instance the option would be to run a SQL Server Managed Instance or a VM with SQL Server installed.

Answer (score 0):

Please reference this blog:[How to delete large data of table in SQL without log?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24213299/how-to-delete-large-data-of-table-in-sql-without-log).

If you don't want to use truncate, M.Ali gives you an another option:

1. change your database's Recovery Mode to SIMPLE.
2. delete rows in smaller batches using a while loop.

Example:

```
DECLARE @Deleted_Rows INT;
SET @Deleted_Rows = 1;


WHILE (@Deleted_Rows > 0)
  BEGIN
   -- Delete some small number of rows at a time
     DELETE TOP (10000)  Crumbs
     WHERE CrumbId < <= @maxId and
           TenantId =@tenantId
  SET @Deleted_Rows = @@ROWCOUNT;
END
```

Maybe you can try this option.

Hope this helps.

Comment: can't change recovery mode to simple because it is Azure DB,and this code will increase database data storage

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options depending on your table and the records you want to delete:

- What's the proportion of your data you want to keep vs. delete? If you're intent is to delete much more data than you want to keep consider saving the data to a new table and drop the old one.
- If your table is partitioned then you can apply the above approach on a partition basis and switch in/out partitions as needed.
- Your db size is comprised of the log and the data files, if you delete non-contiguous chunks of data your indexes are going to be fragmented, so you'll have a lot of space lost in between (page splits, etc.). Once your done with your deletes run either rebuild or reorganize on the index(s) to clean up this space.
- Once you've rebuilt/reorganized, force clean up the log and the pre-allocated data space using [DBCC SHRINKDATABASE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-shrinkdatabase-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). Note that you might suffer a minor perf impact upon restarting your loads since the db and log files need to grow again.