# SQL Server : cleaning old data takes too long

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to clean old data (around 5000 entries in each table) from my SQL Server database, but it takes too long (more than an hour) as I'm looping a CURSOR inside another one.

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE @UserId int
    DECLARE @productNum varchar(50)

    DECLARE user_ids CURSOR FOR SELECT id
    FROM Users
    WHERE productId IN (SELECT ap.id 
                        FROM Account AS a, AccountProduct AS ap 
                        WHERE a.id = ap.accountId 
                          AND a.name IN ('XXXXXX', 'XXXXXX', 'XXXXXX', 'XXXXXX'))
    
    DECLARE product_cur CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT ap.id 
        FROM Account AS a, AccountProduct AS ap
        WHERE a.id = ap.accountId 
          AND a.name IN ('XXXXXX', 'XXXXXX', 'XXXXXX', 'XXXXXX') 
    
    OPEN user_ids

    FETCH NEXT FROM user_ids INTO @UserId

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        OPEN product_cur 

        FETCH NEXT FROM product_cur INTO @productNum

        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
            DELETE FROM UserRole 
            WHERE userId = @UserId 
              AND productId = (SELECT id 
                               FROM AccountProduct 
                               WHERE number = @productNum)
                
            DELETE FROM AccountProduct 
            WHERE number = @productNum

            FETCH NEXT FROM product_cur INTO @productNum
        END
        CLOSE product_cur 

        DELETE FROM Users 
        WHERE id = @UserId 
          AND accountId IN (SELECT id FROM Account 
                            WHERE name IN ('XXXXXX', 'XXXXXX', 'XXXXXX', 'XXXXXX'))

        FETCH NEXT FROM user_ids INTO @UserId
    END

    CLOSE user_ids
    DEALLOCATE user_ids
    DEALLOCATE product_cur 
END
```

Do you know a better way to do that task?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Not using a `CURSOR` would be a start, especially a cursor inside a cursor. SQL is a set based language, and you should be using set based solutions.

Comment: Is the above even the full SQL? For example, you reference the cursor `room_cur`, however, you never declare it.

Comment: @Larnu, it's my mistake, room_cur is product_cur, I edited the question. sorry for the error

Answer (score 1):

This is too long for a comment, however, this should be enough to give you the right idea. It seems, however, that the SQL above isn't the full SQL, so I can't give you SQL that would give you the same behaviour (for example you reference a cursor `room_cur` in your `FETCH` statements, however, there is no cursor `room_cur` declared in the SQL).

SQL is a set based language, it excels at set based solutions. Cursors are **not** set based solutions, they are iterative tasks and SQL Server sucks at it. That is *by design*. SQL is not a programming language so writing it like a programming language means poor performance.

For a `DELETE` statement, you just need to treat it like any other statement, as `DELETE` deletes rows from the defined table in the dataset returned from the `FROM`. For your `DELETE` on `Users`, this (probably) means you want something like this:

```sql
DELETE U
FROM dbo.Users U
     JOIN dbo.Account A ON U.acccountID = A.id
WHERE A.[name] IN ('XXXXXX', 'XXXXXX', 'XXXXXX', 'XXXXXX');
```

This is only `DELETE` the rows in `dbo.Users` where a joined row was found in `dbo.Account` and the value in `name` is in the `IN` clause.

Answer (score 1):

You can go for frequent committing with deletion. I would suggest to delete one userid at a time in a transaction and commit them.

```sql
Go for batch based deletion.

DECLARE @UserIdsToDelete TABLE(RowNo int, UserId int)
DECLARE @ProductsToDelete TABLE(RowNo int, ProductId int)

INSERT INTO @UserIdsToDelete
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY UserId) as RowNo, UserId
    FROM Users
    WHERE productId IN (SELECT ap.id 
                        FROM Account AS a, AccountProduct AS ap 
                        WHERE a.id = ap.accountId 
                          AND a.name IN ('XXXXXX', 'XXXXXX', 'XXXXXX', 'XXXXXX'))

INSERT INTO @productsToDelete
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ap.id) as RowNo, ap.id 
        FROM Account AS a, AccountProduct AS ap
        WHERE a.id = ap.accountId 
          AND a.name IN ('XXXXXX', 'XXXXXX', 'XXXXXX', 'XXXXXX') 


DECLARE @UserIdForDeletion INT
DECLARE @RowNoForDeletion INT = 1

SET @UserIdForDeletion = (SELECT UserID from 
@UserIdsToDelete 
WHERE RowNO = @RowNoForDeletion )
 
-- Deletion of Users
WHILE (@UserIdForDeletion IS NOT NULL )
  BEGIN

BEGIN TRY
        SET XACT_ABORT ON

        BEGIN TRANSACTION

   DELETE FROM UserRole
   WHERE UserId = @UserIdForDeletion 
   AND productId IN (SELECT ProductID from @ProductsToDelete)

    DELETE FROM Users 
        WHERE id = @UserId 
          AND accountId IN (SELECT id FROM Account 
                            WHERE name IN ('XXXXXX', 'XXXXXX', 'XXXXXX', 'XXXXXX'))

    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH

        IF XACT_STATE() <> 0 
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    
        THROW;
    END CATCH

@RowNoForDeletion += 1;
SET @UserIdForDeletion = (SELECT UserID from 
@UserIdsToDelete 
WHERE RowNO = @RowNoForDeletion )
END

-- Delete the account products
BEGIN TRY
        SET XACT_ABORT ON

        BEGIN TRANSACTION
DELETE FROM AccountProduct 
            WHERE number IN (SELECT ProductID from @ProductsToDelete)
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH

        IF XACT_STATE() <> 0 
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    
        THROW;
    END CATCH
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't use cursor as it would definitely affect the performance of the query. Why not execute the deletion in a smaller batches to speed up the query execution time?
[How to delete large data of table in SQL without log?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24213299/how-to-delete-large-data-of-table-in-sql-without-log)