# How to drop table in SQL with 300000 row using MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have table called "emp_manager"  in employees database in SQL. It has 300153 rows. I want to delete entire table in SQL. I used drop table emp_manager; but, it is taking time and server does not respond it.

Can anyone help me to delete this table ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGjSJ.png)

Comment: Truncate is also taking too much time and sql workbench is getting hang. Is there any other way around to delete table with 300000 rows ?

Comment: 300 thousand rows isn't that much, so if it it takes soe much time is there much traffic n the server?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **truncate table emp_manager**

Comment: Truncate is also taking too much time and sql workbench is getting hang. Is there any other way around to delete table with 300000 rows ?

Comment: Maybe delete rows in batches by using where clause

Comment: Maybe this would be helpful : https://stackoverflow.com/a/24213640/11278043

Answer (score 0):

Maybe first delete the rows from that table by using Truncate command and then drop this empty table with drop table.

Comment: Truncate is also taking too much time and sql workbench is getting hang. Is there any other way around to delete table with 300000 rows ?