# Delete 130 million rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server 2012, I need to delete 100+ million rows from a table with 4-5 indices.

How can I proceed? I guess that the transaction log will be full and thus cancel the transaction.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Based upon what criteria?

Comment: Are you deleting more than 50% of the rows, or fewer than 50%. (different strategies for each).

Comment: @tgolisch 80% deleted

Comment: Gordon was quicker than me. If you are deleting more than half, it is usually better to copy the data (that you want to keep) to a new table (without indexes), then apply indexes after the data is moved. Drop the old one, rename the new one.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the size of the table, you might find it faster to empty and repopulate:

```
create table temp_t
    select *
    from t
    where <i want to keep conditions>;

truncate table t;

insert into t
    select *
    from temp_t;
```

In the longer term, you may want to add partitions so it is easier to delete rows.  For instance, partitioning by date would allow you to drop old records with a minimum of overhead.

Comment: it's already partionned by date. i need to drop every date older than 3 months and not that is not an end of month. I already have a view for valid dates so i do delete where not in valid dates but again there is too much to delete

Comment: If you cannot use this method you can read through this post by Aaron Bertrand  about batch deletes and view his test results. https://sqlperformance.com/2013/03/io-subsystem/chunk-deletes

Answer (score 0):

If you

- use the [simple recovery model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/recovery-models-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) and
- don't need to delete all those rows in a single transaction,

it should suffice to do a **chunked delete**. Lots of examples can be found in various related questions here on SO and on dba.SE (e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11230225/87698) or [that one](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/1750/5273)). To make this answer self-contained, I will quote one of those examples (taken from [this answer by gbn](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/1751/5273) and slightly modified) here:

```
SELECT 'Starting' --sets @@ROWCOUNT
WHILE @@ROWCOUNT <> 0
    DELETE TOP (10000) MyTable WHERE <some condition>
```